# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 15: Prove that if $x\leq 0$, then the remainder term $R_{n,0}$ for $e^x$ satisfies $|R_{n,0}|\leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem from Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 15. Prove that if $x\leq 0$, then the remainder term $R_{n,0}$ for $e^x$ satisfies
>
> $$|R_{n,0}|\leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

**My question is about the solution in the solution manual, which I show below.**

First let me show my own attempt at solving this problem. If $x=0$, both sides are $0$. Assume $x\lt0$.

$$e^x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}+\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}, \quad t\in (x,0)$$

We know that for $t<0$ we have $0<e^t<1$.

Thus,

$$|R_{n,0,e^x}(x)|=\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}|x|^{n+1}<\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Is my attempt correct?

---

**When I looked at the solution manual, however, I was slightly bewildered.** Here is what it has

$$\left | \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{n!}(x-t)^n dt \right |= \int_x^0 \frac{e^t}{n!} |x-t|^n dt $$

$$\leq \int_x^0 \frac{|x-t|^n}{n!} dt, \text{since } e^x\leq 1 \text{ for } x\leq 0$$

$$=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Why is the solution manual using an integral, and what is the expression $\frac{e^t}{n!}(x-t)^n$? It looks like a remainder, but I don't understand the $t$ in the $x-t$ factor that is the same as the exponent in $e^t$.

Comment: I'm currently working on a solution right now. I do have one question though: how did you get $e^{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}+\frac{e^{t}}{\left(n+1\right)!}x^{n+1}$? Shouldn't the index start at $i=0$ and $n\to\infty$, and where did the $e^t$ for $t \in (x,0)$ come from? That doesn't look right to me, and even if it is, you don't end up using the $\leq$ sign in your proof.

Comment: @Accelerator the index should start at $0$, the $1$ there is a typo. As for the entire expression I have for $e^x$, that is the result of Taylor's Theorem. Ie, $e^x=P_{n,0}(x)+R_{n,0}(x)$, where $P_{n,0}(x)$ is the n-th order Taylor polynomial at $0$ and $R_{n,0}(x)$ is the Lagrangian remainder term, which includes some unknown $t$ between $x$ and $0$.

Comment: I see. I'll edit my post then.

Comment: @evianpring Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your attempt is correct.

##### The solution manual uses the Taylor series with remainder in integral form

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$
While you are using the Taylor series of $e^x$ at $x=0$ with the remainder in Lagrange form,
$$e^x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}+\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}, \quad \text{for some }t\text{ between } 0\text{ and } x$$
the solution manual is using the Taylor series of $e^x$ at $x=0$ with [the remainder in integral form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
$$e^x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}+\int_0^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n \d t, $$
where $f(x)=e^x$ and $f^{(n+1)}(t)$ is $\left.f^{(n+1)}(x)\right|_{x=t}$, the $n{+}1$-th derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=t$.

We know the magical, wonderful and confusing fact that $f^{(m)}(x)=e^x$ for any positive integer $m$. Hence, the $n$-th remainder term for $e^x$ at $x=0$
$$R_{n,0}(e^x)=e^x-\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}=\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{n!}(x-t)^n \d t.$$
Yes, the variable $t$ in the $x-t$ factor is the same as the exponent $t$ in $e^t$ in the integration above, of course. It has nothing to do with the $t$ in the numerator $e^t$ in the remainder in Lagrange form, though.

The former $t$ is a dummy variable that has nothing to do with $x$ and $n$. We can rewrite
$\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{n!}(x-t)^n \d t$ as $\int_0^x \frac{e^y}{n!}(x-y)^n \d y$ or $\int_0^x \frac{e^a}{n!}(x-a)^n \d a$ or replacing $t$ with any letter of your choice except $x$.

However, the latter $t$ depends on $x$ and $n$. In fact, we can express that $t$ in terms of $x$ and $n$:

$$t=\log\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{x^{n+1}}\left(e^x-\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}\right)\right)\quad\text{ for all }x.$$
The Tayler series you used just says that $t$ as defined/computed above is well-defined and between $0$ and $x$.

##### A proof for the Taylor series with remainder in integral form

Let us prove some more general cases.

For any $f(x)$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ is continuous from $a$ to $x$ inclusive, we have for all $0\le k\le n$,
$$\begin{equation}\tag{*}\label{*}
f(x)=f(a)+{\frac {f'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+\cdots +{\frac {f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}}(x-a)^{k}+\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}}(x-t)^{k}\d t\end{equation}$$

Proof: The fundamental theorem of calculus states that
$$f(x)=f(a)+\int _{a}^{x}\,f'(t)\d t,$$
which is the case of $k=0$. (Note that $0!=1$, $(x-t)^0=1$).

Integrating the last term of $\eqref{*}$ by parts we arrive at

$$\begin{aligned}\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}}(x-t)^{k}\,dt=&-\left[{\frac {f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}}\frac{(x-t)^{k+1}}{k+1}\right]_{t=a}^{x}+\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+2)}(t)}{k!}}\frac{(x-t)^{k+1}}{k+1}\d t\\
=&\ {\frac {f^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)!}}(x-a)^{k+1}+\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+2)}(t)}{(k+1)!}}(x-t)^{k+1}\d t.\end{aligned}$$
Substituting this into the formula in $\eqref{*}$ shows that if it holds for the value $k$, it must also hold for the value $k + 1$, as long as $k\lt n$. Since it holds for $k = 0$, it must hold for every integer $0\le k\le n$.

<sub>The proof is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder), slightly adapted.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [text](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/05%3A_Convergence_of_the_Taylor_Series-_A_%E2%80%9CTayl%E2%80%9D_of_Three_Remainders/5.01%3A_The_Integral_Form_of_the_Remainder), we can prove we can rewrite a general remainder term $R_{n,a}(x)$ in an integral form:

$$f\left(x\right)-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{f^{\left(j\right)}\left(a\right)}{j!}\left(x-a\right)^{j}=\frac{1}{n!}\int_{a}^{x}f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(t\right)\left(x-t\right)^{n}dt.$$

Translating that over to our situation, suppose $x \leq 0$ and $f(x) = e^x$. Assuming you meant $R_{n,0} = R_{n,0}(x)$, we get that remainder term to be

$$
\eqalign{
\left|e^{x}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}\left[\frac{d^{i}}{dx^{i}}e^{x}\right]_{x=0}\left(x-0\right)^{i}\right| &= \left|\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}\left[\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n+1}}e^{x}\right]_{x=t}\left(x-t\right)^{n}dt\right| \cr
&= \left|\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{t}}{n!}\left(x-t\right)^{n}dt\right| \cr
&= \int_{x}^{0}\frac{e^{t}}{n!}\left|x-t\right|^{n}dt. \cr
}
$$
Since $t \in [x,0]$, we have $e^t \in [e^x,1]$. Thus,

$$
\eqalign{
\int_{x}^{0}\frac{e^{t}}{n!}\left|x-t\right|^{n}dt &\leq \int_{x}^{0}\frac{1}{n!}\left|x-t\right|^{n}dt \cr
&= \frac{1}{n!}\int_{x}^{0}\frac{x-t}{\left|x-t\right|}\left(x-t\right)^{n}dt \cr
&= \frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}\left(x-t\right)^{n}dt \cr
&= \frac{x^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)!} \cr
&= \frac{\left|x\right|^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)!}. \cr
}
$$

> In addition, is my attempt correct?

Yes.

> Why is the solution manual using an integral?

**(Opinion)** As someone who doesn't own a Spivak textbook, I'm not sure why the author chose an integral approach. There's an easier way to prove the problem, but maybe the author considered my proof trivial. I expanded on the solution manual because it seemed like you were confused about it as a whole.

Hopefully, this post sheds some light.

Comment: The expression for $e^x$ is just Taylor's Theorem applied to $e^x$ at $0$. It is not an approximation.

Comment: My bad. Your attempt is correct then. @evianpring